# PHP - counting an imploded array

Tags: php, arrays, explode, implode

I am trying to use `sizeof` or `count` to return the number of things inside the array, however whenever I use the `$rank_ids2` to count rather than entering `1, 2, 3, 4, 67, 7` in manually, it just returns `1`, but when I type them in the array directly, it counts 6 just fine!

```
$ranksAllowed = '|1|2|3|4|67|7|';

$rank_ids = explode('|', trim("|".$ranksAllowed."|", '|'));
$rank_ids2 = implode(", ", $rank_ids);

$arrayofallowed = array($rank_ids2);
echo sizeof($arrayofallowed);
```

`$rank_ids` is just turning the |1|2|.. format into 1, 2

Comment: `implode` returns a string; it converts an array to a string. So if you put that string inside a new array, as you have, you end up with an array containing one element.

Comment: If you want to count how many "ranks" are there, move your count to above the implode and `count($rank_ids)` while it is still an array. You could also use substr_count to count how many `, ` exist in the string and add 1. Edit: I guess since you are assigning the string to a new variable, you could just `count($rank_ids)` without moving it above the implode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first solution to your problem would be to initially define `$ranksAllowed` as an array instead of a pipe-character-delimited string:

```
$ranksAllowed = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 67, 7);
```

This would make more sense in almost any foreseeable situation. *If* for some reason you'd rather keep `$ranksAllowed` as a string...

## Some simplification

```
$rank_ids = explode('|', trim("|".$ranksAllowed."|", '|'));
```

can be simplified to:

```
$rank_ids = explode('|', trim($ranksAllowed, '|'));
```

## Decide on string or array format

Right now it looks like you're trying to do 2 things at once (and achieving neither)

One possibility is you want to turn your pipe-delimited ("|1|2|3|...") string into a comma delimited string (like "1, 2, 3, ..."). In this case, you could simply do a string replace:

```
$commaDelimited = str_replace('|', ',', trim($ranksAllowed, '|'));
```

The other possibility (and I believe the one you're looking for) is to produce an array of all the allowable ranks, which you've already accomplished in an earlier step, but assigned to `$rank_ids` instead of `$arrayofallowed`:

```
$arrayofallowed = explode('|', trim($ranksAllowed, '|'));

//Should print out data in array-format, like you want
print_r($arrayofallowed);

//Echo the length of the array, should be 6
echo count($arrayofallowed);
```

Answer (score 1):

`implode` converts an array to a string, so after everything you get this:

- A string named `$ranksAllowed` that contains `|1|2|3|4|67|7|`
- An array named `$rank_ids` that contains multiple elements, being them `1`, `2`, etc...
- A string named `$rank_ids2` that contains `1,2,3,4,67,7`
- An array named `$arrayofallowed` with only 1 element, being it the string inside `$rank_ids2`

To achieve a string that contains `1,2,3,4,67,7` from `|1|2|3|4|67|7|` you can just trim the `|` character as you do and replace `|` with `,`. Is less CPU expensive.

```
$rank_ids2 = str_replace("|", ",", trim("|".$ranksAllowed."|", '|'));
```

If you want to count them you can `explode` it and count the elements:

```
$rank_ids2_array = explode(',', $rank_ids2);
echo sizeof($rank_ids2_array);
```

or with your code you can simply count the already exploded `$rank_ids`.

```
echo sizeof($rank_ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
$ranksAllowed = '|1|2|3|4|5|67|7|';
$rank_ids = explode('|', trim($ranksAllowed, '|'));
echo count($rank_ids);
```

Just to explain the above, the $arrayofallowed is imploding the array of $rank_ids, creating a string. This will not give you the expected results when counted. If you simply count the $rank_ids (as explode() will leave you with an array), you should see the desired result of 7 items.

The $rank_ids is your array, and $arrayofallowed was a string.

Please see the sections of the PHP manual related to the implode() and explode() functions for more information.